# React Video Player onTimeUpdate execute function when video watched some percentage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make some trigger when video watched %60 some function would execute.

Assign onTimeUpdate attribute on video tag.`<video onTimeUpdate={ onPlaying }/>`

```
const [currTime, setCurrTime] = useState(0);

const onPlaying = () => {
    setCurrTime(videoRef.current.currentTime);
    console.log(Math.round(currTime));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (Math.round(currTime) > 5) {
      console.log('Trigger');
    }
  }, []);
```

When I pass the currTime as secondParameter it works but trigger every update.
I want to trigger only once when video reached some defined value.